# Adding Double Quotes and Comma around Query Results Using Derived Column in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to add double quotes and comma for every field value in my query result using ssis derived column. I can't figure out how to use the expresion in derived column to achieve this.  can someone please help?  here is what i am expecting to see in my output text file after the conversion:

```
Name      Location
"ABC",     "CLT",
"NYZ",     "ATL",
"MYX",     "LA",
```

and so forth..
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expression

```
"\"" + Name + "\","
```

The `\` works as an escape character.